Highchart Dashboards DataGridClickCallbackFunction(this, event)
i need an example for the use of  Highchart Dashboards for DataGridClickCallbackFunction(this, event) .. thank you
need an example for usage of this function inside javascript for get the value of the column of a clicked row/Column

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should refer to dataGridOptions.events.row.click function.
API reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/dashboards/#interfaces/DataGrid_DataGridOptions.DataGridRowEvents
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rq8kwmnL/
dataGridOptions:{
    events: {
        row: {
            click: function(){
                console.log(this)
            }
        }
    }
}

